# How to get nodes with long labels in line

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm new to graphviz and I am trying to get the following graphic

[graph without labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv0Ii.png)

However when I want to add labels, the layout inside the first cluster is destroyed.
If I change the constraint the layout in the first cluster is like it should however the edge from the first cluster to node D changes. Here the image with example labels

[graph with labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVhE.png)

Here is the code for the graph with label, as a newbee I might have included some redundant code:

```
    digraph Name { 
    graph [fontsize=10 fontname="Verdana" compound=true];
    { rank=same;
    0 [style=invis];

    01 [style = invis];
        02 [style=invis];
       0-> 01 -> 02 [style=invis];
    }
```

subgraph cluster1 {
compound=true ;
fontsize = 20;
label = "ooooooooooo oooooooo";
A [label="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"];
{rank="same";
B [label="bbbbbbbbbb"];
C [label="cccccccccccc"];
0;
01;}

{rank="same"; 
edge [style=invis];
B1 [label="b1b1b1b1 b1\nb1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1b1"];
C1 [style=invis];}

{rank="same"; 
edge [style=invis];
B2 [label="b2b2b2b2b2 b2b2b2\nb2b2b2b2b2"];
C2 [style=invis];}

A->B ;
0->B [style=invis];
B->B1 [group=g1];
B1->B2 [group=g1];
A->C ;
01->C [group=g2 style=invis];
C->C1 [group=g2 style=invis];
C1->C2 [group=g2 style=invis];
style = "dashed";
}

subgraph cluster2 {
style=invis
{rank=same;
D [label="ddddddd dddd"];
D1 [label="d1d1d1"];
D2 [label="d2d2d2d2d2d"];
D3 [label="d3d3d3 d3d3d3d"];
02;}
02 -> D [style=invis]; 
D -> D1;
D1 -> D2;
D2 -> D3;
}

// edges between clusters
C -> D [ ltail=cluster1 constraint=false];
}
</code></pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
node[ width = x ];
```

where x is a number that fits your labels.

I used

```
node[ width = 3 ];
```

on line 17 and

```
node[ width = 2 ];
```

on line 45 of your code to get this:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Though I don't realy understand why the constraint command for the edge from the first subcluster to the second, changes how the nodes are aligned inside the first subcluster.
However the main issue is it works with your solution!